# Form fields are empty when created using instance = instance

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models `prodcut_prices` and `WrongPrice`.

In `WrongPrice` the user can correct report wrong prices - when the price is reported it should also be updated in `product_price`.

My problem is, even though I instantiate `product_price` at the very beginning as `instance_productprice`, all of its required fields returns the "this field has to be filled out" error.
How come those field are not set when im using the instance `instance_productprice = product_prices.objects.filter(id=pk)[0]` ? Note, that all fields in `product_prices` are always non-empty since they are being pulled from the `product_price` model, which is handled in another view, thus that is not the issue.

```py
def wrong_price(request,pk):
     
    #Get the current price object
    instance_productprice = product_prices.objects.filter(id=pk)[0]
     
    #Get different values
    wrong_link = instance_productprice.link 
    img_url = instance_productprice.image_url 
    wrong_price = instance_productprice.last_price
    domain = instance_productprice.domain
        
    # Create instances
    instance_wrongprice = WrongPrice(
    link=wrong_link,
    correct_price=wrong_price,
    domain = domain)


    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_wrong_price = wrong_price_form(request.POST,instance=instance_wrongprice)
        
        # Update values in product_prices
        form_product_price = product_prices_form(request.POST,instance=instance_productprice)
        form_product_price.instance.start_price = form_wrong_price.instance.correct_price
        form_product_price.instance.last_price = form_wrong_price.instance.correct_price

        
        if form_wrong_price.is_valid() & form_product_price.is_valid():
            form_wrong_price.save()
            form_product_price.save()
            
            messages.success(request, "Thanks")
            return redirect("my_page")
        else:
            messages.error(request, form_product_price.errors) # Throws empty-field errors, 
            messages.error(request, form_wrong_price.errors)
            return redirect("wrong-price", pk=pk)
    else:
        form_wrong_price = wrong_price_form(instance=instance_wrongprice)
        return render(request, "my_app/wrong_price.html",context={"form":form_wrong_price,"info":{"image_url":img_url}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am bit confused about how you implemented it. You have passed a instance of `WrongPrice` price through the form, which is unnecessary, you could have used [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values):

```
wrong_values = dict(
    link=wrong_link,
    correct_price=wrong_price,
    domain = domain
)

form_wrong_price = wrong_price_form(initial= wrong_values)
```

Then you are adding values to `product_prices_form` from instance of `form_wrong_price`. I don't see why you need a form again here. You can simple use:

```
form_wrong_price = wrong_price_form(request.POST, initial= wrong_values)
if form_wrong_price.is_valid():
    instance = form_wrong_price.save()
    instance_productprice.start_price = instance.correct_price
    instance_productprice.last_price = instance.correct_price
    instance_productprice.save()
```

Finally, please use `PascalCase` when defining class names. And you can get the product prices by `product_prices.objects.get(id=pk)`(instead of filter()[0]).

Comment: Thanks for the improvement tips. My issue is that my `product_prices` instance has some empty fields. (there's 8 in total, I am only updating two of them), which I don't understand, since the instance is created from the object pulled from the database, where the fields are non-empty

Comment: The idea is basically; I want to get the instance of `product_prices` with the given primary-key. All of the fields in the `product_price` instance but `start_price` and `last_price` are to be kept i.e I only want to update those two fields (and of course save the new `wrong_price` instance)

Comment: Yep, that’s basically what I did in the answer. Please give it a try and let me know if there is any errors.

Comment: Aaah, sorry. I didnt saw the changes after the `is.valid()` check! It works almost (I might've forgotten to write it) but the user can only fill out 1 of 4 fields. I parse the remaning 3 fields in the `wrong_value_dict` but it seems like they are deleted i.e when I check the database afterwards those values are empty. Do I need to set them manually even when setting `initial=wrong_values_dict` if so, what is the purpose of `initial`  in a POST request?

Comment: It worked by setting those values manually, I just wonder why they aren't set when setting `initial=wrong_values_dict`

Comment: do you have those fields in `fields` attribute of form meta class?

Comment: if I call `object._meta.get_fields()` ? Yes, those fields are there

Comment: i mean in form, not the model :)

Comment: You mean when I define my form - I have those yes in my "original" `product_price_form` (they are to be filled out by the user)

Comment: "so, what is the purpose of initial in a POST request? " well, I was wrong here. It does not make sense to use it in POST request, but it should pre-fill the data in GET request(I updated the answer). And when user submits form, those data should come along in the request.POST data.